# How to use truststore and keystore to store certtifiactes in C# to establish a SSL secure connection to a SOAP service

Tags: c#, ssl, keystore, soap-client, truststore

My client has given three crt files by a third party and they asked to send this as my web request truststore along with my certificate as Keystore. But I don't find any such concept of `Keystore` and `Truststore` in C#.

What I need to achieve is the SOAP request with `Keystore` and `Truststore` in c#

Comment: Keystore is used to store private key and identity certificates that a specific program should present to both parties (server or client) for verification. Truststore is used to store certificates from Certified Authorities (CA) that verify the certificate presented by the server in SSL connection.

Comment: bro i need the calling and storing procedure of truststore and keystore in HTTPWebRequest for c#